# Making DIVs responsive

Tags: css, html

I have a section which have 4 div's, which are centered.

I need to make next:

When screen width is greater than 1280px it display 4 div's in a row,
When screen width is smaller than 1280px it need to display 2 div's per row
And when screen width is smaller than 640px one per row.

html

```
<section class="gallery">
  <div class="flex flex--center">
    <div class="gallery-div">    
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-div">    
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-div">    
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-div">    
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

css

```
.flex{
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.flex--center{
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.gallery-div{
    background-color:pink;
    width:300px;
    height300px;
    margin:10px 5px;}

@media (max-width: 640px) {
  .home-section .flex {
    display: block;
  }
```

Comment: why not to use bootstrap?

Comment: it is a college project, so i need to build grid my self

Comment: Bootstrap is completely unnecessary for something this trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Bootstrap for this is completely unnecessary!

You can do this with some simple CSS:

```css
.gallery-div{
    background-color:pink;
    width: 100%;
    height:300px;
    float: left;
}
.gallery-div:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;  
}

@media (min-width: 640px) {
    .gallery-div{
      width: 50%;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1280px) {
    .gallery-div{
      width: 25%;
    }
}
```

```html
<section class="gallery">
  <div class="center">
    <div class="gallery-div">    
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-div">    
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-div">    
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-div">    
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @Timur You might want to look into the benefits of using `box-sizing: border-box;` for grids using % based widths.

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap grid, you can set a col width per size.

**The Bootstrap grid system has four classes:**

- xs - Extra Small (for phones)
- sm - Small (for tablets)
- md - Medium (for desktops)
- lg - Large (for larger desktops)

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

You can add multiple classes so for example:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can apply this class to your *gallery-div*

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"></div>
```

It will make your row show 1 image in xs (extrasmall), show 2 in sm (medium) and show 4 on greater screens; md (medium and large/lg )

Hopefully it clarifies it a little bit :)